# Function running outside of zsh script

Tags: function, terminal, zsh

recently i discovered this wierd functionality of mac terminal, where if there is a function in my script, i can execute it just by typing it's name in terminal. For example i got script "myscript.sh" with alias in zshrc "myscript". My question is how to prevent 'superFunction' from running straight from terminal just by typing it and to require user to use name of script to run it.

```
#!/bin/zsh
function superFunction(){
        echo $[2+2]
}
superFunction
```

I've tried renaming script, changing alias in zshrc but I am sure its not the right way. I have started learning terminal scripts very recently so my knowlege is on quite low level. I would appreciate any advice

Comment: Remove the line `superFunction`, that's running the function when you run the script.

Comment: And you'll need to use `source myscript.sh` to define the function in your current shell.

Comment: Don't use `$[...]`. That's an old, pre-POSIX form of arithmetic expression that I assume `zsh` only supports for `bash` compatibility, and `bash` itself deprecated it  so long ago that it doesn't even document it (though for whatever reason, support was never actually removed from `bash`). Use `$((...))` instead.